# Writing a swap buffer UART for STM32

Tags: stm32, c, uart

I'm having a logical problem which I can't figure out. I would like to write a safe in terms of synchronization of UART on STM32F103.
I have two buffers that I swap between them in case interrupt has been occurded.

Here is my attempt.

```
vu16 rin[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
vu16 rout[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

#define CHANNELS 3

static int memA[CHANNELS][UART_BUFSIZE];
static int memB[CHANNELS][UART_BUFSIZE];
static volatile int *writeBuffer[CHANNELS];
static int *readBuffer[CHANNELS];

void Init_UART_Buffers(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<CHANNELS;i++) 
    {
        writeBuffer[i] = memA[i];
        readBuffer[i]  = memB[i];
    }

}
/******************************************************************************/
/************************* Externe Service Routinen ***************************/
/******************************************************************************/
void USART_IRQHandler(char Channel, USART_TypeDef *USARTx)
{
     unsigned int IIR;
    IIR = USARTx->SR;
    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_RXNE)
    {                  // read interrupt
      USARTx->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_RXNE;             // clear interrupt

          writeBuffer[Channel][rout[Channel]++] = USART_ReceiveData(USARTx);
        
    }

    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_TXE)
    {
      USARTx->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_TXE;              // clear interrupt
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/
int GetCharUART (char Channel)
{
    int next = readBuffer[Channel][rin[Channel]++];
    int buf;

    int j;
        
    if (!next) { // assuming \0 meant end, swap buffersd
            for ( j = 0; j < UART_BUFSIZE; j++)  
            {
                        readBuffer[Channel][j] = 0; 
            } 
            
            
            buf = writeBuffer[Channel][rout[Channel]];
        // Swap the write buffer to the beginning of the read buffer.
        // If the interrupt fires now, before this assignment, then it
        // will write to the old write buffer
        // which will shortly be our read buffer, and thus we will not lose dat.
        writeBuffer[Channel][rout[Channel]] = readBuffer[Channel][rout[Channel]];
        // if the interrupt fires now then it will write to the
        // new write buffer, which is the old read buffer, 
        // and thus we will not lose data.
        readBuffer[Channel][rout[Channel]] = buf;
        rout[Channel] = 0;
            
            if(rin[Channel] > UART_BUFSIZE)
                rin[Channel] = 0;
    }
    return next;

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want a 'circular buffer'. Then there's no need to swap. I'd suggest you seek out the Arduino core code for the STM32f103 'blue pill' which should have a nice working example.

Comment: @Kartman I wanna fix for learning purposes the  current code

Comment: disable interrupts, swap your buffer, re-enable interrupts.

Comment: @Kartman That causes a lot of interrupt latency. I wanna fix the above code please :)

Comment: @AhmedSaleh that is the correct fix. Otherwise try the [exclusive instructions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/the-cortex-m3-processor/memory-model/synchronization-primitives).

Comment: ‘A lot of interrupt latency’? Implement as suggested, get your code working then measure how many clocks the interrupts are disabled for. Then decide if that is ‘a lot’. You can manipulate the primask level rather than disable all interrupts.

Comment: Using DMA in circular mode is not difficult with this micro.

Comment: all the users has propsed other soultions, while I would like to see a fix for the code above :)